# Javascript Observable infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularfire2

I am building a Chat application, and when a new `message` gets added to a list, I need to update the `chat` item that contains the `message` list.

I am using AngularFire2, and have an `Observable`. This `Observable` works perfectly to dynamically maintain a list as expected.

I do however, have a conundrum. When the list changes I need to perform an `update` which in turn causes the list to change, and so on resulting in an **infinite loop**.

**code:**

The following is the `Observable`

```
findMessages(chatItem: any): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.af.database.list('/message/', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
        }
    }).map(items => {
        const filtered = items.filter(
            item => ((item.memberId1 === chatItem.memberId1 && item.memberId2 === chatItem.memberId2)
                || (item.memberId1 === chatItem.memberId2 && item.memberId2 === chatItem.memberId1))
        );
        return filtered;
    });
}
```

I populate a list with this `Observable`

```
findAllMessages(chatItem: any): Promise<any> {
    return this.firebaseDataService.findMessages(chatItem).forEach(firebaseItems => {
        chatItem.lastMsg_text = 'updated value';
        this.firebaseDataService.updateChat(chatItem);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I update the `chatItem`

```
updateChat(chatItem: any): firebase.Promise<void> {
    return this.findChat(chatItem).forEach((chatItems: any[]) => {
        if (chatItems.length > 0) {
            for (let i: number = 0; i < chatItems.length; i++) {
                return this.af.database.object('/chat/' + chatItems[i].$key).update({
                    timestamp: chatItem.timestamp,
                    negativtimestamp: chatItem.negativtimestamp,
                    lastMsg_text: chatItem.lastMsg_text,
                    lastMsg_read1: chatItem.lastMsg_read1,
                    lastMsg_read2: chatItem.lastMsg_read2
                });
            }
        } else {
            this.createChatFromItem(chatItem);
        }
    });
}
```

**Question**

My confusion here, is that I am updating the `chats` and not the `messages`, so why is the `messages` `Observable` being triggered? Is there a way to achieve this avoiding the infinite loop?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could handle all of this in a much simpler way... The way you mixed Promises & Observables feels a bit convoluted.

Have you looked into [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)?

To put it very simply, you could have a Subject "publishing" any changes in your chat application by calling

```
yourSubject.next(newChatMessage)
```

From then on, subscribing to that Subject from any parts of your application, you'd be able to make any updates necessary.

Then if you want to dig deeper into the subject of state management, you could have a look at the following:

[RxJS powered state management for Angular applications, inspired by Redux](https://github.com/ngrx/store)